# How to log all exceptions in Oracle package?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to log all exceptions in an Oracle package.  Here's what I have at the end of the procedure:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO VSLogger (MESSAGE) VALUES ('Caught Exception');
```

This works fine, however I also want to log the error code and message.  I've tried:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO VSLogger (MESSAGE) VALUES ('Caught Exception: Error ' || SQLCODE || ', Msg: ' || SQLERRM);
```

But this gives me the error:

```
490/7    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
490/100  PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

What's the correct way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `SQLERRM` directly - you have to assign it to an intermediate variable. Note that Oracle 9i would let you get away with it, but that has always been the [documented behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/13_elems50.htm). See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#CJAJBAJG) for some sample code.

You could also consider wrapping this bit in an autonomous transaction, so it gets logged even if your PL/SQL code's transaction gets rolled back.

Answer (score 21):

Never use `SQLERRM` or `SQLCODE`.  Exception logging without storing the line number is cruel.

Always use `dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace`, or something similar.

For example, the following block shows the error but not where it happened:

```
declare
    v_number number;
begin
    v_number := 1/0;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/

DBMS Output:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

This block shows both the error and where it happened.  This is critical information for troubleshooting any non-trivial program.

```
declare
    v_number number;
begin
    v_number := 1/0;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
/

DBMS Output:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

---

(Below is some generic exception handling advice.)

For real code you would *not* want to simply output the error information.  In fact, the best exception handling strategy is usually to do nothing, and use Oracle's default behavior to display all the error messages and line numbers.

Custom exception handling in Oracle is generally only useful in one of these three cases:

1. You are going to do something with a *specific* error, like call another procedure of just ignore the error.
2. If this is a database-only program, then you might want to catch and log exceptions at the *top* of the program, at the (limited number) of entry points.  You don't need exception handling if the application already catches everything, or for inner code.  Exceptions propagate up the stack, it's best to catch them at the end.
3. If you need to log some specific value that only exists as a local variable, it has to be logged immediately, since that value won't propagate with the exception.

There's a lot of PL/SQL code that blindly catches and logs errors in every procedure.  That is unnecessary and usually counter-productive.

Comment: You raise an interesting point.  Why do we have exceptions if the best strategy is to use Oracle default?  Simply to override the default behavior in some scenario?  Can you provide a use case?

Comment: @alexherm I added some more information to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Gaius gave you the short answer. His comment about wrapping it into an autonomous transaction is very important. You'll rue the day your transaction got rolled back, and you don't know why.

Here's something showing using an autonomous transaction with a few extra details thrown in so you know a whole bunch more about where your error occurred.

Your exception block becomes something like this:-

```
exception
   when exception_pkg.assertion_failure_exception then
      rollback;
      raise;
   when others then 
      rollback;
      v_code := SQLCODE;
      v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 255);
      exception_pkg.throw( exception_pkg.unhandled_except, v_code || ' - ' || v_errm || ' ($Header$)' );
```

... aaaand, here's all the code you need to support this. Play around with it, it's useful :-)

```
-- Create a table to hold the error messages

CREATE TABLE ERROR_MESSAGES
(
  ERROR_MESSAGE_ID   NUMBER(10)                 NOT NULL,
  ERROR_DATE         TIMESTAMP(6)               DEFAULT SYSDATE               NOT NULL,
  ERROR_USER         VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)          DEFAULT USER                  NOT NULL,
  MESSAGE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  PACKAGE_NAME       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  PROCEDURE_OR_LINE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  ERROR_CODE         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  ERROR_MESSAGE1     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  ERROR_MESSAGE2     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  ERROR_MESSAGE3     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  ERROR_MESSAGE4     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ERROR_MESSAGES_XPK ON ERROR_MESSAGES
(ERROR_MESSAGE_ID);

-- Create the sequence used for the ERROR_MESSAGES PK

CREATE SEQUENCE ERROR_MESSAGE_SEQ
  START WITH 1;

-- The package

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE EXCEPTION_PKG 
as

   /************************************************************************************
   * $Header$
   *
   * Package: exception_pkg
   *
   * Purpose: Exception handling functionality
   *
   * Authors: M.McAllister (via AskTom - http://tinyurl.com/c43jt)
   *
   * Revision History:
   *
   * $Log[10]$
   ******************************************************************************************/

   /*=====================================================================
   * Constants
   *=====================================================================*/

   c_InfMsg    constant error_messages.message_type%type := 'Informational';
   c_WarnMsg   constant error_messages.message_type%type := 'Warning';
   c_ErrMsg    constant error_messages.message_type%type := 'Fatal Error';
   c_DbgMsg    constant error_messages.message_type%type := 'Debug';
   c_MaintMsg  constant error_messages.message_type%type := 'Maintenance';

   /*=====================================================================
   * Exception Definitions
   *=====================================================================*/

   unhandled_except              constant number := -20001;
   unhandled_except_exception    exception;
   pragma exception_init(unhandled_except_exception, -20001);

   bad_parameter                 constant number := -20002;
   bad_parameter_exception       exception;
   pragma exception_init(bad_parameter_exception, -20002);

   assertion_failure             constant number := -20003;
   assertion_failure_exception   exception;
   pragma exception_init(assertion_failure_exception, -20003);

   /*=====================================================================
   * Procedures
   *=====================================================================*/

   procedure write_exception_info( p_msg_type   error_messages.message_type%type
                                 , p_pkg_name   error_messages.package_name%type
                                 , p_func_name  error_messages.procedure_or_line%type
                                 , p_error_code error_messages.error_code%type
                                 , p_msg1       error_messages.error_message2%type
                                 , p_msg2       error_messages.error_message3%type
                                 , p_msg3       error_messages.error_message4%type
                                 );

   procedure who_called_me( p_owner      out varchar2,
                            p_name       out varchar2,
                            p_lineno     out number,
                            p_caller_t   out varchar2,
                            p_my_depth   in number default 3
                          );

   procedure throw( p_exception in number
                  , p_extra_msg in varchar2 default NULL
                  );

end exception_pkg;
/

-- Package Body

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY EXCEPTION_PKG 
as

   /************************************************************************************
   * $Header$
   *
   * Package: exception_pkg
   *
   * Purpose: Exception handling functionality
   *
   * Authors: M.McAllister (via AskTom - http://tinyurl.com/c43jt)
   *
   * Revision History:
   *
   * $Log[10]$
   ******************************************************************************************/

   /*=====================================================================
   * Types
   *=====================================================================*/

   type myArray is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;

   /*=====================================================================
   * Globals
   *=====================================================================*/

   err_msgs  myArray;

   /*=====================================================================
   * Procedures
   *=====================================================================*/

   procedure who_called_me( p_owner      out varchar2,
                            p_name       out varchar2,
                            p_lineno     out number,
                            p_caller_t   out varchar2,
                            p_my_depth   in number default 3
                          )
   as
       call_stack  varchar2(4096) default dbms_utility.format_call_stack;
       n           number;
       found_stack BOOLEAN default FALSE;
       line        varchar2(255);
       cnt         number := 0;
   begin

       loop
           n := instr( call_stack, chr(10) );
           exit when ( cnt = p_my_depth or n is NULL or n = 0 );

           line := substr( call_stack, 1, n-1 );
           call_stack := substr( call_stack, n+1 );

           if ( NOT found_stack ) then
               if ( line like '%handle%number%name%' ) then
                   found_stack := TRUE;
               end if;
           else
               cnt := cnt + 1;
               -- cnt = 1 is ME
               -- cnt = 2 is MY Caller
               -- cnt = 3 is Their Caller
               if ( cnt = p_my_depth ) then
                   p_lineno := to_number(substr( line, 13, 6 ));
                   line   := substr( line, 21 );
                   if ( line like 'pr%' ) then
                       n := length( 'procedure ' );
                   elsif ( line like 'fun%' ) then
                       n := length( 'function ' );
                   elsif ( line like 'package body%' ) then
                       n := length( 'package body ' );
                   elsif ( line like 'pack%' ) then
                       n := length( 'package ' );
                   elsif ( line like 'anonymous%' ) then
                       n := length( 'anonymous block ' );
                   else
                       n := null;
                   end if;
                   if ( n is not null ) then
                      p_caller_t := ltrim(rtrim(upper(substr( line, 1, n-1 ))));
                   else
                      p_caller_t := 'TRIGGER';
                   end if;

                   line := substr( line, nvl(n,1) );
                   n := instr( line, '.' );
                   p_owner := ltrim(rtrim(substr( line, 1, n-1 )));
                   p_name  := ltrim(rtrim(substr( line, n+1 )));
               end if;
           end if;
       end loop;

   end who_called_me;

   /*=====================================================================
   * PRIVATE function: get_session_info
   * purpose:   Returns a formatted string containing some information
   *            about the current session
   *=====================================================================*/

   function get_session_info return varchar2 is

      l_sessinfo     varchar2(2000);

   begin

      select
         '[SID = ' || sid || '], ' ||
         '[SERIAL# = ' || serial# ||'], ' ||
         '[MACHINE = ' || replace(machine,chr(0),'') || '], ' ||
         '[OSUSER = ' || osuser || '], ' ||
         '[PROGRAM = ' || program || '], ' ||
         '[LOGON_TIME = ' || to_char(logon_time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss') || ']' into l_sessinfo
      from v$session
      WHERE audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','sessionid');

      return l_sessinfo;

   end get_session_info;

   /*=====================================================================
   * procedure: write_exception_info
   * purpose:   Call the exception logging routine
   *=====================================================================*/

   procedure write_exception_info( p_msg_type   error_messages.message_type%type
                                 , p_pkg_name   error_messages.package_name%type
                                 , p_func_name  error_messages.procedure_or_line%type
                                 , p_error_code error_messages.error_code%type
                                 , p_msg1       error_messages.error_message2%type
                                 , p_msg2       error_messages.error_message3%type
                                 , p_msg3       error_messages.error_message4%type
                                 ) is

   -- This procedure is autonomous from the calling procedure.
   -- i.e The calling procedure does not have to be complete
   -- for this procedure to commit its changes.
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
   l_sessinfo     varchar2(2000);

   begin

      l_sessinfo := get_session_info;

      insert into error_messages
         ( error_message_id
         , error_date
         , error_user
         , message_type
         , package_name
         , procedure_or_line
         , error_code
         , error_message1
         , error_message2
         , error_message3
         , error_message4
         )
      values
         ( error_message_seq.nextval
         , sysdate
         , USER
         , p_msg_type
         , p_pkg_name
         , p_func_name
         , p_error_code
         , l_sessinfo
         , p_msg1
         , p_msg2
         , p_msg3
         );

      commit;

   exception
      when others then
         -- We don't want an error logging a message to
         -- cause the application to crash
         return;

   end write_exception_info;

   procedure throw( p_exception in number
                  , p_extra_msg in varchar2 default NULL
                  ) is

      l_owner        varchar2(30);
      l_name         varchar2(30);
      l_type         varchar2(30);
      l_line         number;
      l_exception    number;

   begin

     who_called_me( l_owner, l_name, l_line, l_type );
     write_exception_info( c_ErrMsg
                         , l_owner || '.' || l_name
                         , 'Line ' || l_line
                         , p_exception
                         , p_extra_msg
                         , NULL
                         , err_msgs(p_exception)
                         );
     raise_application_error( p_exception
                            , 'Exception at ' || l_type || ' ' ||
                              l_owner || '.' || l_name || '(' || l_line || '). ' ||
                              err_msgs(p_exception       ) || '. ' || p_extra_msg
                            , TRUE );

   exception
      -- we will get this when we have an invalid exception code, one
      -- that was not set in the err_msgs array below.  The plsql table
      -- access will raise the NO-DATA-FOUND exception.  We'll catch it,
      -- verify the exception code is in the valid range for raise_application_error
      -- (if not, set to -20000) and then raise the exception with the message
      -- "unknown error"

     when NO_DATA_FOUND then
         if ( p_exception between -20000 and -20999 ) then
            l_exception := p_exception;
         else
            l_exception := -20000;
         end if;

        write_exception_info( c_ErrMsg
                            , l_owner || '.' || l_name
                            , 'Line ' || l_line
                            , p_exception
                            , p_extra_msg
                            , NULL
                            , '**UNKNOWN ERROR**'
                            );
         raise_application_error( l_exception
                                , 'Exception at ' || l_type || ' ' ||
                                  l_owner || '.' || l_name || '(' || l_line || '). ' ||
                                  '**UNKNOWN ERROR**' || '. ' || p_extra_msg
                                , TRUE );

   end throw;

begin

   -- This code is run once per session when this package is first touched

   err_msgs( unhandled_except ) := 'Unhandled exception';
   err_msgs( bad_parameter ) := 'Invalid parameter passed into function or procedure';
   err_msgs( assertion_failure ) := 'Program execution stopped due to assertion failure';

end exception_pkg;
/
```

Comment: Awesome!  I'll mess around with that tomorrow.  So far, I know the exception is "no data found" but I have no idea where it comes from or what's throwing it.

Comment: That most often comes when an embedded SQL statement does a select into a set of variables, and rather than having one row returned, no rows are returned.

Comment: Yea, though the problem with this is it happens intermittently about 10 times a day, for no rhyme or reason!  You refresh the page with the same query, and then it works again.  Been trying to track down the cause for over a week now.

Comment: Use the package above, and it will log for you the line in your code the exception is being thrown at. That's one of the advantages of it. Glad to help, as you can tell from the comments in my code, I've put it together from lots of other places, and it's one of the standards in my code workbelt :-)

Comment: I haven't been able to get the package to install correctly.  I get the error `115/12   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` - However, line 115 is in the middle of a comment so I have no idea what it's talking about.

Comment: Oh it's erroring out on the line `from v$session` - What is `v$session` and where do I get it?

Comment: Ok I'm even more confused.  I can run `select * from v$session` just fine, however I get the error when the package refers to it.

Comment: Are you compiling the package into the same schema you can select from? It's obviously a grants issue, the question is ... which grant in particular of course.

Comment: Yup, I'm pasting the `create package` code directly into SQLPlus so I can see the line numbers.  I've already created the tables, indexes and sequences just fine.  Here's a paste of exactly what I'm doing: http://pastie.org/3344018

Comment: Get your DBA to log in as SYS and execute:- grant select on v_$session to <owner of the procedure>; Then try again.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it..  I'm gonna try out jonearle's idea as well.  However, I pretty much know the exact line the error occurs at (it's basically an array index out of bounds) but I don't know why it's happening (the array value was clearly set, but vanished into thin air)..

Comment: You'll already have dbms_utility.format_error_stack as a result of using my package. Adding dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace may be interesting, I'll have to play with it myself.

Comment: McAlister thanks for this solution. i have implemented this in my application. while testing this using scenario: merge with multiple rows returning, i am getting application error raised and not logging into  error messages table as well. need some help on this.